# Need 10 outputs per line

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

I am having trouble refining some code. My code takes a number "n" and calculates that many prime numbers. I need to display 10 primes per line of output data. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n, i = 3, count, c;

   printf("How many primes would you like?");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   if ( n >= 1 )
   {
      printf("2");
   }

   for ( count = 2 ; count <= n ;  )
   {
      for ( c = 2 ; c <= i - 1 ; c++ )
      {
         if ( i%c == 0 )
            break;
      }
      if ( c == i )
      {
         printf(" %d",i);
        count++;
      }

      i++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect when you never output a newline (\n) anywhere?

Comment: Note that your prime determination mechanism is crude (meaning slow) in the extreme.  Effective, but very, very slow.  Try looking for 10,000 primes (104729 is the 10,000th prime).

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
printf(" %5d", i);
   /*     ^ to help align the numbers
```

and

```
if ((count + 1) % 10 == 0)
    fputc(stdout, '\n');
```

fix for the first time when you already print `2`.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool is_prime(int anyNum)   //takes an integer array returns, is_prime
{
    bool is_prime = true;
for (int c = 2; c <= anyNum - 1; c++)
{
    if (anyNum % c == 0)
    {
        //printf("%d is not prime\r\n" , anyNum);
        is_prime = false;
    }
}
return is_prime;
} 

int main()
{
int num_primes;
printf("How many primes would you like: ");
std::cin >> num_primes;

printf("\r\nScanned Primes Are---\r\n");
int foundPrimes = 0;
int x = 0;
for (; x <= num_primes; x++)
{
    bool gotLuckyFindingPrime = is_prime( x );
    if (gotLuckyFindingPrime)
    {
        if (foundPrimes % 10 == 0)
        {
            printf("\r\n");
        }
        printf("     %d", x);
        foundPrimes = (foundPrimes + 1) % 10;
    }
}
}
```

Does handle ten digit showing on cmd too, you can experiment with formatting